# C - How to convert unsigned int seconds to string of date

Tags: c, date, data-conversion, strftime

I have a problem with the conversion of seconds into date. I'm reading a binary file, thus i read as "unsigned int" and it gives me seconds. Then i have to convert it to the date and print. I tried to use strftime but the last input element needs "struct tm" pointer.

I thought calculating by diversing seconds into other things such as 60 for minutes etc. But there is the fact that February may take 29 days in 4 years.

Thus, can anybodu help me for this problem? 
Thanks.

Comment: You'll need to know the point in time from which the seconds are offset.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming your seconds are *seconds since* 1/1/1970 you can use `localtime()` to convert such seconds (epoche time) to a `struct tm` which you can then feed to `strftime()`.

Using `localtime()` takes into account the time zone settings of the machine doing the conversion.

If you are interested in GMT you can alternativly use `gmtime()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I realized that i haven't seen "since the epoch" written to the sheet - in fact wiki.kernel. Anyway, now i coded in the way you told and get the date.

Comment: @user1983481: You are welcome. If you look this answer you are free to upvote it. If it is the correct answer you might even accept it by clicking the white check mark.